# Jquery Mobile Application Installation

Tags: jquery, android, mobile, installation

How to install jquery mobile application in mobile? Is there a way in which we can create any .apk  file /executable file /jar file/ some thing as like we do in android just install .apk file to make application running ?

(note: not as we run by keeping it in server and run in webview ; it should open on icon double click and itself open in webview /browser )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use phonegap. It allows you to run your jQuery mobile websites. But when you create apps using phonegap, it is recommended that you use templates and only request the data from the server. i.e., the presentation must be packed with the app. If you need to update the presentation, you need to update the app. Otherwise, some app stores might reject your app.

Comment: so you mean to say i cant use phone gap for building executable file if i have not used phone gap templates in my app.

Comment: No. You can use. It is just that some time Apple's app store would reject your application. And there is no phone gap template. It is just template like mustache or dust.js or handlebar.js. The reason is, you can submit your app to Apple's app store and when they evaluate your app, it pulls all the html files from the server and displays something. After that they approve your app, and later you can just change the whole thing from the server, and user will see entirely a different app. To avoid such issues, you can pack the presentation (html stuffs) into the app & get the data from server.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of PhoneGap to deploy your HTML5 web app on a device.

http://phonegap.com/

Comment: is there any thing else other than phone gap and if not how can i create .apk file in phone gap